# Pint Python module in MetPy - pint.UnitRegistry TypeError - unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, numpy, module, package, metpy

I'm trying to use a newish Python package for meteorological purposes, MetPy. It relies on using Pint to support units. I'm struggling to import any of the basic modules of MetPy because of an error in the Pint/units part, which is part of the code for importing all sub-modules. (This isn't my code, this is from the package)

```
from __future__ import division
import pint
import numpy as np
units = pint.UnitRegistry(autoconvert_offset_to_baseunit=True)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'autoconvert_offset_to_baseunit'
```

In the basic Pint documentation here (http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nonmult.html) this is a common command as an 'alternative to raising an error', so I can't work out why it isn't working here.

Does anyone have any experience of Pint and know what might be the problem? I'm new to Python and haven't used Pint before today.

Comment: When I get an error like this, I first check that I didn't misspell the argument name (in this case, I don't think you did), then I check the version of library.  What version of `pint` do you have installed?  It looks like `autoconvert_offset_to_baseunit` was added in 0.6 (https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/commit/7b4cc5e53af6fe0fe6ac4540f62b756382414349).

Comment: Thank you so much, that has worked! That will teach me to check versions in future, I had just installed the default on my editor. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The current release of `pint`, 0.7, broke a few things in MetPy. Since the `pip` installer automatically installs the newest version of `pint`, you have to manually uninstall `pint` 0.7 and install `pint` 0.6, e.g.

```
pip uninstall pint
pip install 'pint<0.7'
```

After you do that, the MetPy examples should run.